# d3 chart update automatically when data change by using vue

Tags: d3.js, vuejs2, vue-component, c3.js

I want every time my mock changes and paesss to dataa, the barchart can re-render or updated. I watch dataa in barchart component, but it didn't work.
 "console.log('this', this.dataa);" never trigger. I have no idea which part is wrong.

here is my code:

```
<sr-bar-chart
 :title= "descriptionText.title_traffic"
 :dataa= "mock"
 :unit="descriptionText.avg7d_unit_people"
 :index="'1'"
 :barColor="'#adadad'"
```

and in bar chart component

```
export default {
 name: 'sceneBarChart',
 props: ['title', 'dataa', 'unit', 'index', 'barColor'],
  data() {
  return {
    count: 0
  };
},
watchers: {
  dataa() {
    console.log('this', this.dataa);
    this.drawMap();
  }
 },
 methods: {
  drawMap() {
   ....
  }
 },
 mounted() {
  this.drawMap();
}
```

};

Thanks!

Comment: Could you put together a fiddle/pen/whatever that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `watch` rather than `watcher` and just for good measure I'd add the newValue parameter as well.

```
 watch: {
   dataa(newValue) {
     console.log('this', this.count);
     this.drawMap();
   }
```

here is more info on watched properties: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: Looks like he has a property called `dataa` to me in props.

Comment: @BertEvans You are totally right.  I missed the prop.  Let me look at this some more.

Comment: @BertEvans I have updated my answer based on your feedback and a second review of the code and docs.

Comment: @BertEvans  Are you saying that Vuejs will find a watch method inside a `watchers` object rather than inside a `watch` object?  I checked both the version 1 docs and version 2 docs and I didn't find any indication of that.  So I think the primary reason his `dataa` watcher isn't getting called is that vuejs looks for watch methods inside the `watch` object not inside the `watchers` object. No?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't notice the misspelling.